# Remove excess space between horizontal bar chart and legend in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, graph, charts, space

I would like to remove excess space that is appearing between the legend of my bar chart and where the bars begin. It appears that the amount of this white space changes depending on how many bars are in the chart (determined by the parameters the user selects). Additionally, there is white space about the same size that appears at the bottom of the report.

I have tried updating the custom position and location of the chart and the inner plot. I have tried using the Point Width as well. See highlighted excess space in red pen below.

[image: See highlighted excess space in red pen below]

Comment: have you set the report "consumewhitespace" property to true?